# Excel 2019 wrong subtotals from SSAS cube

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I don't understand why Excel doesn't show the same subtoals as ssas ?

Excel 2019
SSAS 2017

[image]

Comment: The "total" value is NOT calculated by Excel. This is returned from the Cube!. If you run the profiler against the SSAS instance, you can get the actual MDX. If you take this MDX and run it in SSMS, you should be able to see the "total" value. In summary, for calculated measures, the total shown may not be what the users needs! You can "turn off" the totals in Excel by using Design -> Subtotals -> Do Not Show Subtotals menu option.

Comment: Thank you Subbu, it helps me a lot to trace the MDX query. The problem comes from a calculated member.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check to see if the negative number is being accepted in Excel as a negative number

Comment: Could you explain more please